# Detecting if data in a struct has been corrupted before reading it

Tags: c, struct, embedded, corruption

Someone has told me that there are techniques in embedded c where you can check if your data has been corrupted. I am more interested in detecting whether my data has been corrupted because of some other process corrupting the RAM memory.

I have tried to find some information on the internet but I couldn't find anything.

One would be to "surround" the members of a struct with boundary values and before you read these members, you check that these values are still the expected ones:

```
#define BOUNDARY_VALUE 0xDEADBEEF

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t top_boundary;
    int32_t some_data[4];
    uint32_t bottom_boundary;
} tMyDummyStruct;

tMyDummyStruct GetSomeData( void )
{
    return (tMyDummyStruct){
        .top_boundary = BOUNDARY_VALUE,
        .some_data = {1, 2, 3, 4},
        .bottom_boundary = BOUNDARY_VALUE,
    };
}

bool IsDataCorrupted( tMyDummyStruct* data_struct )
{
    if( data_struct->top_boundary == BOUNDARY_VALUE &&
        data_struct->bottom_boundary == BOUNDARY_VALUE)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The other technique would be to create a crc member in the struct and check/update it every time we read/write:

```
typedef struct
{
    int32_t some_data[4];
    uint32_t crc;
} tMyDummyStruct;

uint32_t GetCrcOf( int32_t[] );

tMyDummyStruct GetSomeData( void )
{
    tMyDummyStruct retval = {
        .some_data = {1, 2, 3, 4},
        .crc = 0,
    };
    retval.crc = GetCrcOf(retval.some_data);
    return retval;
}

bool IsDataCorrupted( tMyDummyStruct* data_struct )
{
    if( data_struct->crc == GetCrcOf( data_struct->some_data ) )
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

My questions are: Do you know more techniques or a better one? Is there a place where these techniques are documented?

Thanks

Comment: Googling your exact title gives: 'About 17,300,000 results':(

Comment: Yes, but none related to techniques in c to detect data corruption

Comment: This question is too broad. Check bytes, checksums, ECC, mirror images, defensive programming/sanity checks, march or walkpat tests etc etc. In order to answer your question someone would have to write a whole essay.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what sort of corruption you want to detect and what penalty you are willing to pay in terms of memory and runtime to detect it. It is a tradeoff.

A simple scheme would be a boundary scheme as you suggested in the first example. This would detect if all the bytes in a row or page are corrupted, but will not detect single bit errors.

A slightly more complex scheme would be to store a **parity byte** at the end of your data. This parity is calculated by XORing all bytes in the structure. This would detect single bit errors in data, but would not detect two bit errors. This would not have too much runtime.

Further along the complexity scale you have a **CRC code**. This can be 16 bit or 32 bit and can detect multiple bit errors in data. Read up on *Hamming Distance* to get more information about the number of bit errors that can be corrected.

Then there are **Error Correcting Codes**. These codes can detect multi bit errors and also correct for single or sometimes two bit errors. These are used in fault tolerant microprocessors.